# Reload network interfaces without rebooting

Tags: bash, shell-script, systemd, udev, systemd-networkd

I'm doing a BASH script for Arch Linux in a Raspberry Pi 2. The thing is that in some point I'd like to reload the network interfaces without reboot and have my new named network interfaces (en0 and wl0) when I insert `networkctl`, for instance. The solution I've found is:

Bring the network interfaces down:

```
ip link set <net_if> down ;
```

Modify /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (or its equivalent): in my case it is 10-network.rules. It contains:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa", NAME="en0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb", NAME="wl0"
```

Reload with

```
udevadm control --reload-rules ;
```

Retrigger with

```
udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=net ;
```

Bring the network interfaces up:

```
ip link set <net_if> up ;
```

But it didn't work on my RbPi2.

I've also found on another post that in some point you must insert

```
modprobe -r <driver module>
```

but I can't find my driver module for my wifi dongle (I've tried with `lsusb -v`).

BTW: I'm not using Networkmanager. I have configured the network interfaces with systemd (/etc/systemd/network/). I've also tried reloading the systemd-networkd service.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know Arch Linux. Do you have access to `ifdown` and `ifup`?

Comment: When you say "But it didn't work" do you mean that the network interface did not get renamed, or something else?

Comment: I don't know much about systemd configuration. I've tried to insert the `ifdown` command and Bash returns `-bash: ifdown: command not found`. To Celada: Yes, I want that after the network reload if I insert `networkctl` the shell shows the new network interfaces: en0 and wl0.

Answer (score 1):

to get the driver for a network interface, just use : `ethtool -i en0` and look for the "driver" section :

```
root@odin ~ # ethtool -i eth0
driver: e1000e
version: 2.3.2-k
firmware-version: 0.13-4
```

Here, my driver is e1000e.

Now you can rmmod your driver and modprobe it again. This will also reset the network counters, of course.